# fetching result from mysql and then check for specifc value from a row and count

Tags: php, mysql

`agent` table and `lead_submission` table.

```
 id_agent   agent_name    last_login
 1          xxx          2014-11-28 12:15:47
 2          abc          2014-12-06 12:51:45
 3          cvb          2014-12-12 12:51:45

id_agent      agent_name    entry_date           qa_details                 SelDisposiotn
  1            xxx        2014-11-28 12:15:47    504:Yes|581:|515:No|      Complete Survey
  1            xxx        2014-11-28 12:15:47    504:Yes|581:Yes|515:No|   Complete Survey
  2            abc        2014-12-06 12:51:45    504:Yes|522:|515:No|      Complete Survey
  3            cvb        2014-12-12 12:51:45    504:Yes|532:Yes|515:No|   Partial Survey
```

my query is fetching list of `agent_name` from `agent` table. `count(agent_name)`from `lead_submission` table    `count(qa_details)` from `lead_submission` table `SelDisposition` from `lead_submission` table  `left join lead_submission on lead_submission.id_agent=agent.id_agent`  `group by` `lead_submission.agent_name`

```
<?php
//DB connection goes here

$sql="
SELECT a.agent_name LoginAgent
     , COUNT(s.agent_name) AgentApplicationHit
     , COUNT(s.qa_details) QADetails
     , s.selDisposition Status 
  FROM agent a
  LEFT
  JOIN lead_submission s
    ON s.id_agent = a.id_agent 
 WHERE s.entry_date BETWEEN '2014-11-28 12:15:47' AND '2014-12-06 12:51:45' 
   AND s.SelDisposition = 'Complete Survey' 
 GROUP 
    BY s.agent_name;
";

$query=mysql_query($sql);

?>   
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<table border="1">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>LoginAgent</th>
                    <th>AgentAppliccationHit</th>
                    <th>QA Details</th>
                    <th>Status</th>

                </tr>
  <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{?>

         <tr   style="color:red" >

        <td><?php echo $row['LoginAgent']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['AgentApplicationHit']; ?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row['QADetails']; ?></td>   
        <td><?php echo $row['Status']; ?></td>          
        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
```

my result:-

```
 LoginAgent  AgentAppliccationHit          QA Details                Status
    xxx             2                        2                      Complete Survey
    abc             1                        2                      Complete Survey
```

Till now everything is fine.

Now i have another table `question_details`

```
qno  qshortcode   question
504   PPI         whatever
515   Test        whatever1
```

as you can see these qno `504` and `515` from `question_details` table is in `qa_details` from `lead_submission` table and also in my result where i `count(qa_details)`.

Now how can i get the specific value count from each `qa_details` row in `lead_submission` `504:Yes|522:|515:No|` where values are `504` and `515` are there in each row of `lead_submission` table like

```
LoginAgent   AgentAppliccationHit      504(PPI)     515(Test)        Status
    xxx             2                    2            2            Complete Survey
    abc             1                    1            1            Complete Survey
```

Comment: Normalyze your db. Instead of use concatenation inside lead_submission table, qa_details field use another table and store 1 data for each row -.- That said, you can with php (you tagged it) split the value on each | and then on : and then do something

Comment: ok but how can i get the row `qa_details` of each agent and then //do something

Comment: this line $row['QADetails']; contains 504:Yes|581:|515:No| (example), you can work here, make other query based on the split, etc

Comment: ok man. thnk you for throwing some light

Comment: the line i suggested does contain 2, is taken from the query. You can do a sql query to obtain qa_details of lead_submission

Comment: the line u suggested $row['QADetails']; contains 504:Yes|581:|515:No|   contain 2?? i didnt get it

Comment: in contains 2, on the sql query you are using that field for a count

Comment: Yes Yes i am counting(Qa details) for that user and its 2 between date range

Comment: selDisposition is indeterminate - you can see that, right?

Comment: Where SelDisposition='Complete Survey' in my query fetching rows.

Comment: oh ok - for good form, you should still include it in the group by

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as suggested, you should rather normalize your DB...BUT... you CAN get your counts with your current setup... you will need to use a bit of RAM though...if the questions, agents, client answers and permutations are many.

Edit your query to also return qa_details in the results e.g:

```
SELECT qa_details, a.agent_name LoginAgent ... etc
```

Here goes:

```
 $stats_manager = array(); //or $stats_manager = [] ; depending on your php version.while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
        {    
                 //split up the answers into their respective questions

    foreach(explode('|', $row['qa_details']) as $Question)
        {

         $QnA = explode(':', $Question); //$QnA[0] gives you the $Question number, $QnA[1] is the answer
    $stats_manager[$row['LoginAgent']][$QnA[0]]++; //increment the number of times Agent has a question in his qa_details column
    $stats_manager[$row['LoginAgent']]['AgentApplicationHit'] = $row['AgentApplicationHit']; 
    $stats_manager[$row['LoginAgent']]['QADetails'] = $row['QADetails'];  //still necessary? I doubt.
    $stats_manager[$row['LoginAgent']]['Status'] = $row['Status']; 
    }
        }
```

By now have a multi-dimensional array holding all your agents, and their respective counts of Q's and A's
You can then simply loop the array (i left out the table header and other non-critical bits of the html

```
foreach($stats_manager as $agent_name =>  $stats_data)
{
echo "<tr><td>$agent_name</td>";
//loop hrough all the fields
foreach($stats_data as $key => $value){
echo "<td>$value</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
```

The key here is to avoid echoing anything out until you have collated your data.
Also, although this will work, it is better to normalize

Untested. Should work.

Edit: Realized afterwards I was emptying the `$stats_manager` with every loop. fixed
SO wont let me edit the corrected code so I have removed the initialization of the stats_manager variable, but code will still work, with a "notice undefined variable " warning